# Echo in the same page after using contact form

Tags: php, submit, echo, contact-form

I am working on my website right now and I have encountered a little problem, I am not that great at PHP but managed to put together a contact form that works fine, the code will be below, the thing is that after submitting, I want it to echo on the same page as the button, like underneath it or something like that and I don't quite know how to get there.

Some help please ?

```
        if ( mail($destination,$subject,$mailMessage,$mailHeader) ) 
        {
            echo "Thank You!";
        }           
        else header('Location: index.html');

    }       
    else header('Location: index.html');    

}
else header('Location: index.html');
```

**PS :**

I think i have to change the action attribute to point to itself but I don't quite know how.

**Update - Entire code:**

```
<?php

//EMAIL VALIDATION
function validateEmail($value){
    return preg_match('/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/', $value);
}

//CHECK VARIABLES (EMPTY/NULL OR DEFAULT)
if ( isset($_POST['last']) && $_POST['last']!="Nume complet" && isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email']!="Email" && isset($_POST['message']) && $_POST['message']!="Recenzie/Comentariu" ) {

    //CHECK EMAIL   
    if ( validateEmail($_POST['email']) ) {



        ////////////////////// EDIT HERE  /////////////////////////

        //SET HERE YOUR DESTINATION EMAIL
        //IT SHOULD BE FROM THE SAME DOMAIN WHERE SITE IS HOSTED
        $destination="...@outlook.com";

        //SET HERE YOUR EMAIL SUBJECT
        $subject="Colibri";

        //MESSAGE DATA (HTML FORMATTED)
        $mailMessage.="<dt><strong>Nume complet:</strong></dt><dd>".$_POST['last']."</dd>";
        $mailMessage.="<dt><strong>E-mail:</strong></dt><dd>".$_POST['email']."</dd>";
        $mailMessage.="<dt><strong>Recenzie:</strong></dt><dd>";  
        $mailMessage.=nl2br($_POST['message'])."</dd></dl>";
        $mailMessage = utf8_decode($mailMessage);

        ////////////////////// END EDIT  /////////////////////////



        //SENDER EMAIL
        $mailFrom=$_POST['email'];

        //HEADER DATA
        $mailHeader="From:".$mailFrom."\nReply-To:".$_POST['name']."<".$mailFrom.">\n"; 
        $mailHeader=$mailHeader."X-Mailer:PHP/".phpversion()."\n"; 
        $mailHeader=$mailHeader."Mime-Version: 1.0\n"; 
        $mailHeader=$mailHeader."Content-Type: text/html";


        if ( mail($destination,$subject,$mailMessage,$mailHeader) ) 
        {
            echo "Thank You!";
        }           
        else header('Location: index.html');

    }       
    else header('Location: index.html');    //EMAIL VALIDATION ERROR

}
else header('Location: index.html');        //VARS ERROR
```

?>

**My HTML**

```
<div class="form">
  <hr/>
  <form id="myForm" method="post" action="contact_colibri.php">
    <input type="text" value="Nume complet" id="last" name="last" class="fields" onFocus="if(this.value == 'Nume complet') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Nume complet';}"><br/>

    <input type="text" value="Email" id="email" name="email" class="fields" onFocus="if(this.value == 'Email') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email';}"><br/>   

    <textarea cols="20" rows="5" id="message" name="message" class="fields" onFocus="if(this.value == 'Recenzie/Comentariu') {this.value = '';}" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Recenzie/Comentariu';}">Recenzie/Comentariu</textarea><br/>

    <center><button class="button">Trimite</button></center>

    </form>

            </div>
```

Comment: what happens when you submit the form? You have one if statement and 3 else. Can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: @lgupta Sure thing, I will update the post as we speak with the code. the other else statements bring me to the index instead of displaying a error message if the destination, subject or message are not written in the form, i did not create the echo text for the "No subject written, please chose a subject" ans so on.

Comment: Is your form in a separate file?

Comment: Just to be sure: "contact_colibri.php" is in action, it is the form page?

Comment: @doydoy44 Yes it is, otherwise i will not be receiving the emails :)

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was just to check. :) 
I had a similar problem, the echo was not displayed on the screen. But there was .... before my HTML code. Look in the source code of your HTML page, just in case ... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found out one way of making it happen , Using iframe, the only thing you need to do is add :

```
<div class="form">
  <hr/>
  <form id="myForm" method="post" action="contact.php" target="myIframe">
  ...
  ...
</form>

<iframe name="myIframe" frameborder="0" border="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-style: none;width: 100%; height: 120px;"></iframe>
```

Hope this will come in handy for those trying to find out an answer to this same problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the blank action.

And after form code use this php code:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // your php code here
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try set the action of the form to the same php file, and then check for its parameters and print the message.
Other way could be send the form trough ajax, and then using javascript to print the message.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to post your form using ajax and echo the results in php:

Make sure to include jquery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('form').on("submit", function(){

  var formData = $(this).serialize();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "contact_colibri.php",
    data: formData,
    success: function(result){

       $('.feedback').html(result);   

    }
  });

  return false;
});

</script>
```

In your php file make sure you define the $message = "" variable before you try to append any string value:

```
$message = '';
```

And you are trying to use the $POST['name'] variable which does not exist and is not checked for either add the name field to your html form or just simply use the email from the form:

either add name in html form:

```
<input type="text" value="Name" id="name" name="name" class="fields">
```

or change in php:

```
$mailHeader="From:".$mailFrom."\nReply-To:".$_POST['email']."<".$mailFrom.">\n";
```

and now you don't need to set the header locations just echo the feedback:

```
echo 'Your email did not validate';
echo 'There was a problem sending your email, try again later...
echo 'You did not enter all te required fields';
```

make sure you add a html element with feedback below your form to show the feedback:

below your form submit button:

```
<p class="feedback"></p>
```

Comment: I tried it, it did not work...I added the jquery script you provided on my html page between script tags and it still did not work...

Answer (score 0):

Your form tag should be something like

```
<form method="POST" action="{LINK_TO_FORM_SUBMIT_PAGE}" .... >
```

In your above code. You can redirect back to the contact form on success.

Replace `echo "Thank You!";` with

```
header('Location: {YOUR_CONTACT_FORM_LINK}?success=true');
```

Later, in your contact form page check for this success param.

```
if(isset($_GET['success']) && $_GET['success']) echo 'Thank You!';
```

Comment: I have done so...the only thing it does is redirects to my index page without echoing any message ...

Comment: your form is in the index page?

Comment: No , my form is not in the index page, only that when I made the updates you suggested, after clicking the submit button it redirects me automatically to the index page.

Comment: Did you receive any e-mail? I guess there was some error, in that case it will go back to index page.

Comment: I did receive the email, just tried it again this is how I added what you gave me and the success param somewhere underneath it: '{
    header('Location: contact_colibri.php?success=true');'
   }

Comment: I am not sure try debugging it. This should redirect you to contact_colibri.php on success. Also, the last line `if(isset($_GET['success']) ....` will be added to contact_colibri.php page.

Comment: Sorry, i\ve been out of an internet connection, it is written in my contact_colibri.php, here is a link to my page and you can also see the contact form : http://brilliancedisplay.ro/brilliancedisplay/colibri.html